# How to read H5T_STRING from hdf5 using C

Tags: hdf5

So I have a hdf5 file which contains a dataset:

```
DATASET "updateDateTime" {DATATYPE  H5T_STRING{
    STRSIZE 24;
STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLPAD;
CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
}
    DATASPACE  SIMPLE{ (5) / (5) }
    DATA{
    (0) : "2015-05-12\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000",
    (1) : "2015-05-13\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000",
    (2) : "2015-05-14\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000",
    (3) : "2015-05-15\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000",
    (4) : "2015-05-16\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"
}
```

I want to read this dataset using C, but I can't find a proper example(I am new to HDF5). Specifically, I can't figure which H5T_NATIVE_* to use when reading. Here is the code i have right now:

```
hid_t  time_ds = H5Dopen(grp, "updateDateTime", H5P_DEFAULT);
auto time_shape = get_dataset_shape(time_ds);
char** time_str = (char **)malloc(time_shape[0] * sizeof(char *)); // TODO: memeory allocation correct??

 status = H5Dread(time_ds, H5T_NATIVE_CHAR, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT,
    time_str);
 /*do my stuff*/

free(time_str);
status = H5Dclose(time_ds);
```

Comment: And what happens when you execute this code?

Comment: Well, time_str is not filled with data after H5Dread() @arboreal84

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into the source code of h5dump(the tool goes with hdf5 package), I finally got it to work. I can't say this is a good solution, but hope this can help other people who encounter the similar problem.

It turns out the native type can be speculated by this function

```
hid_t h5tools_get_native_type(hid_t type)
{
hid_t p_type;
H5T_class_t type_class;

type_class = H5Tget_class(type);
if (type_class == H5T_BITFIELD)
    p_type = H5Tcopy(type);
else
    p_type = H5Tget_native_type(type, H5T_DIR_DEFAULT);

return(p_type);
}
```

Then, read the dataset like this:

```
type = H5Dget_type(dset);
native_type = h5tools_get_native_type(type);
auto shape = get_dataset_shape(dset);
n_element = std::accumulate(shape.begin(), shape.end(), 1ull, std::multiplies<size_t>());
type_size = std::max(H5Tget_size(type), H5Tget_size(native_type));
size_t alloc_size = n_element * type_size;
char * buf = BAT_NEW char[alloc_size]; 

status = H5Dread(dset, native_type, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT, buf);

/*do my stuff*/

H5Tclose(native_type);
H5Tclose(type);
delete[] buf;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
char* time_str = (char*) malloc(time_shape[0] * sizeof(char));

status = H5Dread(time_ds, H5T_NATIVE_CHAR, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT, &time_str);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work. time_str is still empty

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could read the dataset (of datatype H5T_STRING) using [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) in C like this:

```c
hdfql_execute("SELECT FROM updateDateTime");
hdfql_cursor_first(NULL);
printf("Dataset value is %s\n", hdfql_cursor_get_char(NULL));
```

In case the dataset stores more than one string (which seems to be your case by looking at the result of h5dump posted above), you can retrieve these by looping the result set:

```c
hdfql_execute("SELECT FROM updateDateTime");
while(hdfql_cursor_next(NULL) == HDFQL_SUCCESS)
{
   printf("Dataset value is %s\n", hdfql_cursor_get_char(NULL));
}
```